PyQt6 video player not showing
I want to do a basic video player using PyQt6 and so far I've managed to create the video and media player but the problem is that when I load a video file, the path is good and all but nothing appears in that targetArea (which is a QWidget) that I have.
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QFileDialog
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QObject, QUrl, QDir, QRect
from PyQt6.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer
from PyQt6.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from pathlib import Path


class VideoPlayer(QObject):
    def __init__(self, ui):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = ui

        # connecting click events
        self.ui.targetArea.mousePressEvent = self.on_target_area_clicked

        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer()

        self.videoWidget = QVideoWidget()

        self.mediaPlayer.errorOccurred.connect(self.handle_media_error)

        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.videoWidget)

        self.videoWidget.show()

    def handle_media_error(self, error):
        print(f'Media error: {error}')

    def on_target_area_clicked(self, event):
        fileDialog = QFileDialog()
        fileDialog.setNameFilter("Video files (*.mp4 *.avi *.mov *.wmv *.mkv *.flv *.webm *.mpeg *.mpg *.mp4v)")

        filePath, _ = fileDialog.getOpenFileName()

        if filePath:
            self.handle_selected_file(filePath)

    def handle_selected_file(self, filePath):
        supported_extensions = ['.mp4', '.avi', '.mov', '.wmv', '.mkv',
                                '.flv', '.webm', '.mpeg', '.mpg', '.mp4v']

        file_extension = Path(filePath).suffix.lower()

        if file_extension not in supported_extensions:
            print(f'{file_extension} is not supported. Please choose another file.')
        else:
            self.handle_video_loaded(filePath)

    def handle_video_loaded(self, filePath):
        video_extensions = ['.mp4', '.avi', '.mov', '.wmv', '.mkv',
                            '.flv', '.webm', '.mpeg', '.mpg', '.mp4v']
        if QUrl(filePath).isLocalFile():
            mediaUrl = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filePath)
        else:
            mediaUrl = QUrl(filePath)

        file_extension = Path(filePath).suffix.lower()

        if file_extension.lower() in video_extensions:
            self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(mediaUrl)
            self.mediaPlayer.play()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Video Player")
        self.resize(1024, 768)

        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.targetArea = QWidget(parent=self.central_widget)
        self.targetArea.setGeometry(QRect(520, 100, 520, 140))
        self.targetArea.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.targetArea.setObjectName("targetArea")

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.video_player = VideoPlayer(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.video_player.videoWidget)

        self.open_button = QPushButton("Open Video File")
        self.open_button.clicked.connect(self.video_player.on_target_area_clicked)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.open_button)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())        

I just want to be able to load a video and see it play. I've tried other methods but so far in vain.

Nothing should appear in targetArea exactly because it's just a normal widget, while the video would eventually appear in the separate videoWidget. In any case, please provide a proper [mre].

I was thinking of creating a QVboxLayout of some sort so I can add them both so it could be able to display it in that targetArea, but since you mentioned that, I don't have to do that at all?

The point is that your targetArea is, right now, completely useless, and adding a further widget to it is a bit pointless. I suggest you to do some research about widget promotion. You could make that targetArea a promoted widget that you would then implement as a QVideoWidget subclass in your code (without the need to create an instance of it). That should make it a valid video surface. But, again, as said above, we cannot help you more unless you provide a proper [mre]: for instance, we don't know how you actually create that VideoPlayer, nor how you use it.
